# python function: r = requests.get (url, auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user,pwd)), r.text return the same text even without credentials

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests


r = requests.get(link, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, pwd))
```

The problem is r.text returns the same information when the part auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, pwd) is deleted.

I login the website with use and pwd and find out that r.text is exactly the same with view page source(the 'view page source' are the same no matter I log in or log out).But the element(right click - inspect - element) are not the same, How to extract the element using python?

Comment: Are you sure the site is HTTPBasicAuth? Also all of the text/csv file nonsense can be removed from the question. If you are certain you are getting back the link, user, and pwd correctly, the file operations are irrelevant to the question. This is a question purely based around python requests.

Comment: So if I am understanding this correctly you are having problems authenticating? IE. you try to authenticate, but you are unable to proceed?

Comment: @CopyandPaste Thanks, I just edit my question. The code was directly copied from a python file that written by someone else.

Comment: right, that's the problem.

Comment: It would help if you could share the URL of the website you are logging into.

Comment: @Robᵩ here it is: https://www.waze.com/trafficview

Comment: As @CopyandPaste surmised, that site doesn't use HTTPBasicAuth.

Comment: @Robᵩ What I want is to run scripts from github.com/DCgov/Waze_TTC, and the URL: waze.com/trafficview as well as user,pwd are provided. So what you mean is, This URL is not for this scripts,  am I right?

Comment: I agree. I believe that those scripts are not designed for that URL.

Comment: @Robᵩ Thanks! My problem finally got solved. However, I couldn't find the button to accept your answer, I am really new to StackOverflow...

Comment: That's because I didn't post an answer, only comments. It would be nice if you created an answer that describes your solution. Then you can accept your own answer!